# Phonegap/Cordova Application Error net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a cordova phone app that is working except now I am getting these weird file not found errors which is crashing the application. I built a phonegap app about 3 years ago (2012) and it has been working fine. I recently re-installed cordova from scratch using command line and plugged my www folder in and the app seems to work most of the time except this error which isn't consistent. I can navigate to and from pages within the app and seemly randomly I get this error while naivigating between pages even if I had already viewed the pages multiple times inside the app all the sudden it says it is not found.

Application Error

net:ERR_FILE_NOTE_FOUND (file:///android_asset/study.html)

This error comes up at different times while trying to load the study.html page, I may have already viewed successfully the study.html page 1 to 5+ times before the error shows up on maybe the 3rd or 6th load it is not consistent on when it shows up.

It happens to more then just this file too, I have about 20 html pages and I have seen this error happen to 3 different files that are all accessible and work then *seemly randomly* the next time I try to load one the error happens.

Any ideas on what it could be? Remember, the entire app works and the page loads most of the time but sometimes while accessing it multiple times it says it doesn't exists and the app crashes with that error.

Thanks.

Comment: I am also facing same issue after upgrading cordova phonegap application from 3.0 to cli-6.5.0. Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently run into the same error. In my case, the error is for index.html, and once it starts happening it happens perfectly consistently for a long time, persisting through reboots of both the phone and the serving computer, but the actual error message is the same. The solution in my case seems to be to open the settings menu in PhoneGap Desktop and click 'save', after which I can load my app in the PhoneGap app again.